# Rails routing: What does only: [] do here?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, url-routing

I saw a piece of Rails code for routing like this:

```
namespace :my do
  resource :auth_states, only: [] do
    collection do
      get 'signed_in'
    end
  end


  resource :password, only: [:edit, :update]      
  # And all the actions a logged in user can perform under "my" namespace...
  # ...

end
```

Supposedly this app works with `devise` and `cancancan` gem. I guess the `:auth_states` part verifies whether a user is signed in or not before he/she can perform all the below actions. However I'm a bit confused by `only: []`. Doesn't that mean no actions whatsoever will be generated for `:auth_states`? How does this thing work then. Does it mean no visitor will be able to visit `auth_states` from outside, but the app itself will still be able to utilize it? Is `only: []` a widely used pattern in Rails?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`only: []` contains an array of whitelisted actions to be routed for the resource. For instance, if you specify

```
resource :auth_states, only: [:index]
```

then only the index action will be generated, therefore

```
GET /auth_states
```

will work, whereas (the new action)

```
GET /auth_states/new
```

will not. Passing an empty action is a trick to use a resource as a namespace for nested routes. In fact, in your case the router will route

```
GET /auth_states/signed_in
```

but, at the same time, will not route

```
GET /auth_states
GET /auth_states/1234
```

Sometimes, you will see it in combination with a `controller` option

```
resource :authentication, controller: 'auth_states', only: [] do
  collection do
    get 'signed_in'
  end
end
```

that generates

```
GET /authentication/signed_in
```

The router has a `namespace` method, but it automatically scopes the controller into a Ruby namespace. Using this trick is sometimes more effective, and allows to group altogether routes that belongs under the same umbrella, prefixing them with a same path.

Answer (score 1):

only: [] is used as an optional parameter so that you can specify allow routing to specific actions of that particular controller - auth_states. In your case it does not seem necessary to use that. If you specifiy certain actions say only: [:index] then index action will be only routed but not others. Hope this clears your confusion.

Comment: My confusion was I thought if it's empty then *all actions* will not be allowed. So what you mean is that it doesn't do anything here because it's empty...  Then is there a reason why the developer included it in the code?

Comment: Yes it can be set empty or better not use it if you don't need to specify certain actions. The developer might have included to provide flexibility here.

Comment: It's not there to provide flexibility, it's a common trick to simulate a namespaced route.

Comment: Yeah now I realized the answer is actually inaccurate but I can't retract the upvotes... Strange voting system.